# Generate all unique 1-1 mappings between two lists of strings (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, recursion, nested-loops

How to you generate a set of all possible 1-1 mappings between two lists. I want each mapping to be unique, but am not too concerned about computation time (brute force is probably fine). Lists can be different sizes, or we can just fill in the shorter list with nulls.

```
Example:
List A = [x, y] (or [x, y, null])
List B = [1, 2, 3] 

Results would be something like:
[[1x,2y,3],
[1x,2,3y],
[1y,2x,3],
[1y,2,3x],
[1,2y,3x],
[1,2x,3y]]
```

Is there a simple way to do this (preferably in Java)? The lists can be any size (and different sizes).

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried two nested `for` loops?

Comment: Where does the 3 in the result come from?

Comment: Ahh sorry about that, I edited it to fix the 3 part. I tried nested for loops but couldn't get the structure right.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is basically just a combination of `List A` with all possible permutations of `List B`.

```
listPermutations
    input: list a , list b

    list result

    //add nulls to b until b reaches the length of a
    extend(b , length(a))

    for list p in permutations(b)
        add(result , combine(a , p))

    return result
```

Comment: I think this might work. I'll give it a shot. Thanks for the quick response